# How do I dynamically update spinner in kivy with values from sqlite without restarting the app

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, kivy

Hell I am beginner in python and kivy trying to create kivy python app that uses sqlite database

My problem is that I do not know how to create a self updating spinner

I want the spinner to update with data I fetch in table user_technical.

As you can see bellow I can fetch the data yet I do not know how to pass what I fetched from database back to spinner value.

It is hard coded now just to show example of how I want it to look.

As well I would be happy to get suggestions after it updates how to store what user has clicked so I can create remove the skill method

```
def refreshSkillsSpinner(self):
        ID = 1903938
        conn = sqlite3.connect("D:/Study-Hub/Study-Hub/studyHub.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT technical_skills, technical_skills_ranking FROM user_technical WHERE student_id = ? ", (ID,))
        data = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close
```

```
            Spinner: 
            id: userAddedTechnicalSkills
            text: "View Your Skills"
            bold: True
            values:["Python        5", "Java       4", "Hardware       6", "3D Modeling        6"
            on_press: root.refreshSkillsSpinner(userAddedTechnicalSkills.text)
```

How it should look https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGtmR.png
Well I will make it look nicer later...

So when I will delete or add entries to database and click it again it should the current amount

Thank you

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ApuCoder Thank you for comment. Does it have to be reproduciable to the point someone can run it? Like I need to provide database file and whole running code app plus imports ?

Comment: The `minimal` part of  `minimal reproducible example` means eliminating the stuff that is not part of the issue. For example, your code that gets data from a database can be replaced by a simple method that just sets the `data` to something representative.